# Converting png images into video

Tags: c#, windows, video-processing, aforge

I'm trying to convert all png images in a give directory to a avi file but I'm running out of memory. I don't have more than 20 images in the directory now, a 4GB ram PC. but I still getting this error. What am I missing?

here's my current code:

```
using (var writer = new VideoFileWriter())
            {
                writer.Open(Path.Combine(dest_path, "output.avi"), width, height, frameRate, VideoCodec.Raw);

                foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dest_path))
                {
                    var img = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(file);
                    writer.WriteVideoFrame(img);
                }
                writer.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On aForget.net forum, it says that the bitmap required to be disposed.

Visit : http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2912

```
using (var frame = BitmapImage2Bitmap(e.ColorFrame.BitmapImage))
    using (var thumb = ResizeBitmap(frame, 320, 240))
    {
         writer.WriteVideoFrame(thumb);
    }
}
```

Try:

```
using (var writer = new VideoFileWriter())
{
    // create new video file
    writer.Open(Path.Combine(dest_path, "output.avi"), width, height, frameRate, VideoCodec.Raw);

    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dest_path))
    {
        using(var img = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(file)) {
            writer.WriteVideoFrame(img);
        }
    }
    writer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Directory.EnumerateFiles is lazy evaluated. And you are writing video file in the same folder where your sources are located. This means that your output file will be enumerated as well. This will lead to video file being passed to image loader.

Try to output to different folder or filter files by extension.